# uniformly continuous functions have a uniformly continuous composition

Tags: functions

If you have a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. And I want to show that $g(f(x))$ is uniformaly continous, where both functions are uniformally continous. Do I just trace the definition through twice. Or does it make a difference in the proof that $f: A \rightarrow B$ rather than $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: try! you'll see.

Comment: I mean, I did the trace. And I think it makes sense. Just want to make sure that I wasn't making an assumption that I can't. I know that since f is unifomarlly continous I get there exist delta such $|x-y|<d$ implies$|f(x) - f(y)|< e$ and that in turn would imply $|g(x) - g(y)|< e$ since g is uniformally continous. ( where is e is epsilon and d is delta)

Comment: that's it :). By the way $\epsilon$ is \epsilon in latex and $\delta$ is \delta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, this is an exercise in notation and book-keeping more than anything.

For one, we know $g$ is uniformly continuous, so for any given $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an $\eta > 0$ such that $d(g(a), g(b)) < \varepsilon$ whenever $d(a, b) < \eta$.

But remember that $a$ and $b$ are outputs from $f$!  Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, then we go through the same process, with $\eta$ taking on the role that $\varepsilon$ played in the previous line.  A sentence more and you'll be finished.

To be entirely rigorous, the metric in $A$, $B$ and $\mathbb{R}$ may be different each time, so you will want to reflect that in your notation.  E.g. $d_A(\cdot , \cdot)$, or in the case of $\mathbb{R}$, the absolute value bars.

Comment: does $d(g(a),g(b)) = |g(a)-g(b)|$?

Comment: Indeed, it means the same thing.